# Creating verilog code from schematic

Tags: verilog, xilinx

[image: schematic attached HERE]

I need to create a verilog code from this schematic.
So far I have:

```
module example1 (X, Y, Z, F);
input X, Y, Z;
output F;
wire w1, w2, w3;

nand
    g0 (X, Y);
    g1 (X, g0);
    g2 (Y, g0);
    g3 (Z, g1, g2);
    g4 (Z, g2, g3);
    g5 (g3, g4);

endmodule
```

This is pretty much my first verilog code. I'm not sure how to add the wires or if I even have the correct number of wire. I see that there are many wires in the schematic, but I don't really know which wire to choose. Please help me improve my code.

Answer (score 1):

`g0` is an instances names of the nand gates; not the name of the output wires. For a nand gate, the first port is always the output and all others are considered inputs.

- `g0 (X, Y);` should be changed to `g0 (w0, X, Y);`
- `g3 (Z, g1, g2);` should be changed to `g3 (w3, Z, w1, w2);`
- etc.
- `g5`'s output should be `F`

FYI: Even with the above corrections, your logic is not correct. Double check your connections.